# How to filter any variables greater than a value in a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I am sure that this is a very simple question and I am upset that I can't solve it.
I have a data.frame (df) looking like this

```
    df <- data.frame("genus" = c("a","b","c","d","e", "f"),
                 "Kit1" =c(0,0,0,102, 10, 2),
                 "Kit2" = c(3,2,0,105,11, 12),
                 "Kit3" = c(1,20,310,102,1,99),
                 "Kit4" = c(0,0,0,190,4,0))
>df
      genus Kit1 Kit2 Kit3 Kit4
1     a    0    3    1    0
2     b    0    2   20    0
3     c    0    0  310    0
4     d  102  105  102  190
5     e   10   11    1    4
6     f    2   12   99    0
```

and I want to filter all rows that contain >100 counts.

```
filter_all(all_vars(.>100) # filters all rows, that contain >100 counts,
```

In my case, only genus "d" is preserved, everything else is discarded, also genus "c" although here Kit3 shows 310 counts.

if I use

```
filter_all(any_vars(.>100) # nothing happens, although for my understanding this would be the correct command
```

I want to preserve all rows, where minimum 1 x 100 counts is exceeded.

I don't know why, but I am a bit lost with this easy question.

You would help me a lot :)
Looking forward for your help!
Kathrin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `if_any` (from  dplyr -version >= 1.0.4)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(if_any(starts_with('Kit'), ~ . > 100))
```

-output

```
#    genus Kit1 Kit2 Kit3 Kit4
#1     c    0    0  310    0
#2     d  102  105  102  190
```

---

If all the 'Kit' column should have value > 100, use `if_all`

```
df %>% 
  filter(if_all(starts_with('Kit'), ~ . > 100))
```

---

If the version is older, could use `filter_at` with `any_vars` (getting deprecated)

```
df %>%
    filter_at(vars(starts_with("Kit")), any_vars(. > 100))
```

Comment: When I try this, I get an error and it tells me that it doesn't know if_any(), although dplyr is loaded..

Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x could not find function "if_any"
i Input `..1` is `if_any(contains("Kit"), ~. > 100)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Maybe the across()-fct is needed?!

Comment: @Kathrin Can you check your `packageVersion('dplyr')`.  I used `1.0.4`

Comment: @Kathrin if you have an older version, then `df %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("Kit")), any_vars(. > 100))` should work, but it may get deprecated

Comment: I updated my version, and now it works :) Thank you very much for your help!